# How to list all of the actors in ULevelStreaming?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I can't find a way to list all the Actors inside sublevel (LevelStreaming). For an enumeration, I try to use TActorIterator, but its constructor accepts a reference to UWorld, it does not accept a reference to ULevelStreaming, since they both inherit from UObject,and ULevelStreaming does not inherit from UWorld. I can list all the Actors from the world like this:

```
  UWorld* world = GetWorld();
    TActorIterator<AActor> Iterator(world, AActor::StaticClass());
    for (; Iterator; ++Iterator)
    {
        AActor* Actor = Cast<AActor>(*Iterator);
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 30.f, FColor::Yellow, Actor->GetFName().ToString());  //Print name of the Actor

    }
```

This works, but I only get objects from the main map (Persistent Level), and I have no idea how to get a list of all the Actors from the additional levels that I add as ULevelStreaming.
This is my try(does not work):

```
    UWorld* world = GetWorld();
auto levels = world->GetStreamingLevels();
for (auto level : levels) {
    ULevelStreaming* currentLevel = Cast<ULevelStreaming>(level);
    TActorIterator<AActor> It(currentLevel, AActor::StaticClass()); //Here is compiler error with TActorIterator's constructor
    for (; It; ++It)
    {
        AActor* Actor = Cast<AActor>(*It);
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 30.f, FColor::Yellow, Actor->GetFName().ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all - level must be loaded. Then you can use **GetLoadedLevel** to get **ULevel**. And **ULevel** already has **Actors** - the array of all actors

```
UWorld* world = GetWorld();
auto StreamingLevels = world->GetStreamingLevels();
for (UStreamingLevel* StreamingLevel : StreamingLevels ) {
    ULevel* level = StreamingLevel->GetLoadedLevel();
    if(!level)
        continue;
    for (AActor* Actor : level->Actors)
    {
        // Actor
    }
}
```